# JSoup timeout not working as expected

Tags: java, timeout, jsoup, socket-timeout-exception

I'm trying to download a page content using JSoup.
If the whole operation (open connection + read) takes more than 8 seconds, I want to abort right away. I assumed that the purpose of the `timeout(int millis)` method does exactly that.
According to the javadoc:

> Set the request timeouts (connect and read). If a timeout occurs, an
>   IOException will be thrown. The default timeout is 3 seconds (3000
>   millis). A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout.

I wrote a simple code that simulates that operation:

```
    final int TIME_OUT = 8000;
    final String USER_AGENT_STRING = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
    final String url = "http://reguler-pmb-tanggamus.va.web.id/";

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(USER_AGENT_STRING).timeout(TIME_OUT).get();
        System.out.println("Done crawling " + url + ", took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " millis");
        System.out.println("Content: " + doc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " millis");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried to run this small script on a few "problematic" websites **in a single threaded environment**.
I assumed that whether it succeeded or an exception was caught, the operation time should never exceed 8 seconds (8000 millis).
Unfortunately, this is not the case as sometimes it succeeds (no exception) after more than a minute:

```
Done crawling http://reguler-pmb-tanggamus.va.web.id/, took 68215 millis
Content: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> ...
```

and sometimes (very rarely though) fail (SocketTimeoutException) after more than a minute.

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem before?

Comment: Which version of JSoup are you using?

Comment: I'm using JSoup version 1.8.3

Comment: I was able to reproduce your finding. I would suggest you file a bug report @ https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues

Comment: An issue has been filed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Problem faced by OP seems to be a bug in Jsoup 1.8.3.

> I was able to reproduce your finding. I would suggest you file a bug report @ github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues (*[luksch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229229/luksch)*)

An issue has been provided by OP: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/628

Answer (score 0):

The JSoup team (jhy) responded to my issue:

> It sets the connect and the read timeouts. Read timeout means the time
>   between reads. If you have a server dribbling content out over a long
>   time, but each read is < 8 seconds, it won't timeout.
>
> It might be nice to implement a max timer but that's not
>   straightforward (needs a monitoring thread and a practical way to
>   shutdown a connection), and that's not something many others have
>   asked for.

Seems like this issue isn't gonna be fixed any time soon.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Set the maximum bytes to read from the (uncompressed) connection into the body, before the connection is closed,
 * and the input truncated. The default maximum is 1MB. A max size of zero is treated as an infinite amount (bounded
 * only by your patience and the memory available on your machine).
 * @param bytes number of bytes to read from the input before truncating
 * @return this Connection, for chaining
 */
Connection maxBodySize(int bytes);
```

Jsoup default recv maximum is 1MB

set "Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(0);" maybe fixed it!